# Flink app's checkpoint size keeps growing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a pipeline like this:

```
env.addSource(kafkaConsumer, name_source)
            .keyBy { value -> value.f0 }
            .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(2)))
            .process(MyProcessor())
            .addSink(kafkaProducer)
```

The keys are guaranteed to be unique in the data that is being currently processed.
Thus I would expect the state size to not grow over 2 seconds of data.

However, I notice the state size has been steadily growing over the last day (since the app was deployed).

[image]

Is this a bug in flink?

using flink 1.11.2 in aws kinesis data analytics.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have multiple events on the same key for a continuous amount of time? If a single key continues to observe events, the session would not be closed, and events on that key would continue to be buffered in state...

Comment: no. we are specifically testing this with unique keys to ensure state doesnt grow (but it does...)

Answer (score 2):

Kinesis Data Analytics always uses RocksDB as its state backend. With RocksDB, dead state isn't immediately cleaned up, it's merely marked with a tombstone and is later compacted away. I'm not sure how KDA configures RocksDB compaction, but typically it's done when a level reaches a certain size -- and I suspect your state size is still small enough that compaction hasn't occurred.

With incremental checkpoints (which is what KDA does), checkpointing is done by copying RocksDB's SST files -- which in your case are presumably full of stale data. If you let this run long enough you should eventually see a significant drop in checkpoint size, once compaction has been done.

Comment: I don't see that happening on Kinesis AWS, the checkpoints have become > 700 MB and they keep on growing. I don't know what "long enough" means, our pipeline is running continuously for 21 days

Comment: @sakisk did you ever resolve this issue? I am facing something similar with a stateful Flink app running on AWS Kinesis Data Analtyics

Comment: Not entirely, but there are a few things that helped: a) switched to the latest Kinesis supported Flink version (1.15.2), b) increased the checkpoint interval to 5 minutes, c) [cleaned up explicit state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76043019/581351). Still not at the level I want, but I think that at this point it's because of `RichAsyncFunction` using external resources (e.g. a relational database)