# Is this a valid Flink StateTtlConfig?

Tags: java, apache-flink, ttl

By reading the [official docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl), it's not clear if I can combine different cleanup options, in this case `cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter` and `cleanupFullSnapshot`.

```
StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
                .newBuilder(Time.minutes(3))
                .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(1000)
                .cleanupFullSnapshot()
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnReadAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### ** I propose you 3 ways **

According to the official Apache Flink documentation, the StateTtlConfig can have only one cleanup option at a time. So in the example you provided, it is not valid to combine the cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter and cleanupFullSnapshot options together.

Therefore, you need to choose one of them based on your use case. The cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter option is generally more efficient, as it only cleans up expired state during RocksDB compaction, whereas the cleanupFullSnapshot option takes a full snapshot of the state and removes all expired state in one go.

So, for example, if you have large amounts of state and you want to minimize the impact on performance, you can use the cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter option with a high cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter value. On the other hand, if you have a smaller amount of state and need to ensure that expired state is removed as soon as possible, you can use the cleanupFullSnapshot option.

### ** 1rst way -**

Here's an example of a valid StateTtlConfig that uses the cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter option:

```
StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
    .newBuilder(Time.minutes(3))
    .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(1000)
    .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnReadAndWrite)
    .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
    .build();
```

### ** 2nd way -**

```
StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
    .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
    .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
    .cleanupFullSnapshot()
    .cleanupInBackground(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
    .build();
```

In this example, we're using the `Duration` class instead of the deprecated Time class. We're also setting the UpdateType to `OnCreateAndWrite`, which means that the TTL will be checked when a new value is written to the state and when it's initially created. We're also using `StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired` to ensure that expired state values are never returned by the Flink job.

Additionally, we're using both `cleanupFullSnapshot()` and `cleanupInBackground(Duration.ofMinutes(1))` to ensure that expired state is efficiently cleaned up both during a full snapshot and in the background at regular intervals. This helps to minimize the impact on the job's performance while still maintaining efficient state cleanup.

Overall, this example provides a more robust and professional configuration for a Flink StateTtlConfig.

### ** 3rd way - **

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateTtlConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time;

StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(3))
    // Only keep data in RocksDB for 1000 records
    .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(1000)
    // Take full snapshot of state to remove expired keys
    .cleanupFullSnapshot()
    // Update TTL on both read and write operations
    .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnReadAndWrite)
    // Never return expired state
    .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
    .build();
```

here i assumes that the required Flink libraries are already imported and that this code is being used within a valid Flink context.

Comment: Can you please add a reference to the "can have only one cleanup option at a time"?