Asynchronous part of checkpoint could not be completed
I am getting following error in my jobmanager.
#0 - asynchronous part of checkpoint 11880 could not be completed.\njava.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121) ~[?:1.8.0_402]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_402]\n\tat org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:511) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]\n\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:54) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]\n\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsyncCheckpointRunnable.finalizeNonFinishedSnapshots(AsyncCheckpointRunnable.java:191) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]\n\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(AsyncCheckpointRunnable.java:124) [flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_402]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_402]\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(T


I have checked the Flink webUI. there is no back pressure. Currently i am using rocksdb statebackend and check points are stored in EFS. I am suspecting  compaction or serialization in rocksdb is taking more time. But i am not getting much info from DEBUG /TRACE logs. I have enabled rocksDB logs but not getting much info from that as well.
As a workaround i have increased the checkpoint timeout, though it works. Would like to undertand the reason behind the initial failure.
Thanks in advance.
Following is the check point configuration.
       state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/conf/checkpoints
            state.storage.fs.memory-threshold: 0
            state.backend.type: rocksdb
            state.backend.incremental: true
            execution.checkpointing.checkpoints-after-tasks-finish.enabled: true
            execution.checkpointing.interval: 10000
            execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention: DELETE_ON_CANCELLATION
            execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 1
            execution.checkpointing.min-pause: 5000
            execution.checkpointing.mode: EXACTLY_ONCE
            execution.checkpointing.timeout: 60000
            execution.checkpointing.tolerable-failed-checkpoints: 0


If the checkpoint was timing out, the problem could be related to i/o quotas or rate limits.

Have you enabled incremental checkpoints? That makes a big difference with RocksDB.

yes it is enabled.

i have updated my question with checkpoint details. It was always timing out in my sink operators (rich sink function) asynchronous part. As per my understanding async part is the one that writes to check point directory(in my case it is EFS ) from rocksdb(it is inside taskmanager.). check pointed data size is 20 to 30MB always. To see the time taken for data transfer from my task manager pod to EFS, i tried manual copy of some dummy data which is of size 120MB. Data transfer was very fast. So there is no network issue as well.

What can i monitor if this error occurs next time?.. network buffers? if yes, can i see this in web UI or logs?

one more point to add is, it is not always timeing out..once in 3 to 4 days it is occuring.

One minute is a very aggressive timeout. The default is 10 minutes for a reason.

One solution might be to set execution.checkpointing.tolerable-failed-checkpoints to something greater than zero. That would handle an occasional hiccup without increasing the timeout.

For now,  I have changed to 10mins as the check point timeout. Hopefully that solves the issue.Thanks David for the reply:).

Now checkpoint time out is not happening. But check point size grows but not drastically. One more observation is when i redeploy taskmanager, jobmanager and job. size becomes 0. Again it starts growing, do i need to add state time to live or it is not needed. As per this comment , it looks like size of check point will be reduced once it reaches the compaction size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429035/flink-apps-checkpoint-size-keeps-growing. Is this understanding correct?
@DavidAnderson

The checkpoint size will grow as the number of active keys rises. It will also grow until compaction begins. Whether or not you need to worry about state TTL (or using timers to manually clear state) depends on whether or not your active state will grow in an unbounded fashion.

I am having flink pipeline with key by, few filters, map , aggregator and windows function. Every 5mins windows function will return the aggregated results. How to find out active state will grow in unbounded fashin or not?..I don't need any state to stay for more than 10mins..

I was checking the state size in a check point with rest API. I see that state size is bigger and check point size is little small.. why ??

With hashmap backed, each state size can go up to 5MB, I am having rocks db back-end, how much is the max size of the state??

State size is only limited by the disk.

as my keyby uses date, i am assuming based on each date and my state will grow. So there are chances it will grow in unbounded way. Aggregate Function is stateless so i cant configure stateTTl there. I am using tumbling window there also no way to add stateTTL. 1.Do i need to convert my tumbling window to some rich functions to access states and clean them up? or 2. is there any way i can do  that with out changing to  rich functions?

Why are you using keyBy with a date? If you can convert this to some sort of windowing, then you can avoid the state build-up. Tumbling windows automatically clean-up their state after the windows are triggered, so shouldn't be anything to worry about there.

keyBy is not exactly using date, but an id related to date that would change everyday. For example, to find sum of tip a taxi driver gets in one hour window in a businessday.  A taxi driver can start his day and end his businessday anytime. Driver A can start at 9 AM and end next day 9AM. At the same time driver B can start at 10AM and end at next day 10AM. In mongo db, at the end of window record is written for each driver. For one day 24 records will be present for a driver in db.

i cant convert 24 hours as window here. So that is the problem. 1 hour is tumbling window. Does states will clean up at the end of tumbling window? if yes, do you mean rocks DB.sst files will be deleted?.

State is freed at the end of each window. The corresponding storage in rocksDB will eventually be compacted away.

i tried with different window time(2s,10s, 5mins) and few times i observed, all .sst files generated in that windows are deleted completely when windows fired and few times few sst files are compacted and only few were present. why is this different? does it mean same key has arrived in next window as well? my latest check point no in prd was 11000, and this was still refering to the very old .sst file(00016.sst ). what could be the reason to keep this old file without compacting it.
